# Jquery select div within common parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider code:

```
<div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="target">        
        <div class="sub1">
            <span class="value">
                10
            </span>
        </div>            
        <div class="sub2">
            <button type="button">Trigger</button>
        </div>            
    </div>

    <div class="target">                
        <div class="sub1">
            <span class="value">
                20
            </span>
        </div>            
        <div class="sub2">
            <button type="button">Trigger</button>
        </div>            
    </div>    
</div>
```

How to select following value. If I click on 'button', I want jquery to select parent `div class="target"` and get `span class="value"` `.text()`.

The trick is to not select direct parent, but to be able to reach multiple level parent

Comment: are you looking for [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){

  var text=$(this).closest('.target').find('.value').text();

});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. With this method I can reach as many level parents as I want. Thank You!